react elements not showing unless I refresh the page
I am working on this template website, and for some reason, when loading into any of the project pages (for example, '/projects/first_year/fall'), all of the links and images in the class 'images' doesn't seem to appear until i refresh the page. i located the missing elements to this element:
<div className="images">
    <div className="image-container">
      <Image className="image" src={example} alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div className="image-container">
      <Image className="image" src={example} alt=""/>
    </div>


    <ul className="linksprj">
  
  <li className="linkprj">
    <Link href={"#"}>LinkedIn</Link>
  </li>
  <li className="linkprj"><Link href={"#"}>Github</Link></li>
  <li className="linkprj"><Link href={"#"}>Facebook</Link></li>
</ul>

which has this CSS:

.linkprj{
  font-size: 2em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}


.linksprj{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 40em;
  z-index: 9;
}

.linkprj:hover{
  color: rgb(7, 147, 255);

}

.link:hover{
  color: rgb(7, 147, 255);
}

.images{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 100%;
}

.image{
  height: 15em;
  width: 15em;
  object-fit: contain;
}

i have no idea why does element disappear, but I am assuming that it's related to the fact that it's a  and a . though, the  in '/projects/about' still renders fine, so I have some doubt about this

I'm not 100% sure about this, since this is 70% testing and 30% random sources, but nextjs does something called pre-fetching, where instead of fetching the entire web page, they instead fetch the website as fast as possible, I'm not sure why or what do they remove. but what I can say is that it will remove things like images or links that require time to load.
to solve this, you need to refresh the page and let nextjs do a full fetch of the pages, you can do this by adding window.location.reload(); to your code, but it does reset the entire website (including useEffect), so you need to do this with a function that also doesn't happen when switching to a new page
the solution I found was to make a small main page that loads well and when moving to any other page, I refresh the page after already switching pages, so the function only happens once.
